# Count unique values of a column given the values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

So, I have a problem with something I thought it was relatively easy.

I have a dataframe with three columns:

```
A  B  C
x1 a  2
x1 a  2
x1 b  3
x1 c  4
x1 c  4
x2 d  2
x2 d  2
x3 e  5
x3 e  5
```

Now, if I want to now for each group of A (x1, x2, x3) how many unique values there are in B which in C are greater than 2, and assign this to a new column D which would return me the following

```
A  B  C  D
x1 a  2  2
x1 a  2  2
x1 b  3  2
x1 c  4  2
x1 c  4  2
x2 d  2  0
x2 d  2  0
x3 e  5  1
x3 e  5  1
```

How should I get this in Python Pandas without using a for loop? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) + [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) + [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
df['D'] = df['A'].map(df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.C > 2, 'B'].nunique()))
print (df)
    A  B  C  D
0  x1  a  2  2
1  x1  a  2  2
2  x1  b  3  2
3  x1  c  4  2
4  x1  c  4  2
5  x2  d  2  0
6  x2  d  2  0
7  x3  e  5  1
8  x3  e  5  1
```

Solution with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) + [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) + [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) + [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) + [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['D'] = df['A'].map(df.query('C > 2').groupby('A')['B'].nunique()).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
    A  B  C  D
0  x1  a  2  2
1  x1  a  2  2
2  x1  b  3  2
3  x1  c  4  2
4  x1  c  4  2
5  x2  d  2  0
6  x2  d  2  0
7  x3  e  5  1
8  x3  e  5  1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can first filter based on column `C`  then use `groupby.nunique`. The resulting Series can be used as a mapping:

```
df['D'] = df['A'].map(df[df['C']>2].groupby('A')['B'].nunique()).fillna(0)

df
Out: 
    A  B  C    D
0  x1  a  2  2.0
1  x1  a  2  2.0
2  x1  b  3  2.0
3  x1  c  4  2.0
4  x1  c  4  2.0
5  x2  d  2  0.0
6  x2  d  2  0.0
7  x3  e  5  1.0
8  x3  e  5  1.0
```

Comment: Bloody great answer